# Java - Swing - TextArea - scrollbar

Tags: java, swing

I want to have a textArea to display results that can be scrolled. The scrollbar doesn't appear even though I set it to VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS
What Am I doing wrong??

```
void addPlayerPanel(JFrame gameFrame) {
      JPanel playerPanel = new JPanel();
      // automatically added to contentPane with gameFrame.add()
      gameFrame.add(playerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      playerPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Registered players"));
      // text are to show registered players
      JTextArea display = new JTextArea(5, 40);
      display.setEditable(true); // set textArea to editable
      display.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
      JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(display);
      scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
      // Add Text area
      playerPanel.add(scroll);
      playerPanel.add(display);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're adding both the JScrollPane AND it's display to the GUI -- DON'T do that. Add just the JScrollPane. It holds the display and that is what you need.

So change:

```
playerPanel.add(scroll);
playerPanel.add(display);
```

to

```
playerPanel.add(scroll);
// playerPanel.add(display);
```

Question: why are you setting the layout manager of your JTextArea? That really makes little sense.

Comment: Thanks it works now, I got rid of display.setLayout as well. keeping the borderlayout

Comment: @user3162260: keeping what BorderLayout? You don't set any component's layout with BorderLayout in the code above.

Comment: gameFrame.add(playerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); This doesn't do anything? Is that because it's automatically centred?

Comment: @user3162260: that's not setting the layout of any container. It is specifying what position in a BorderLayout using container you'd like the component added to, but is not necessary since the default position location in such a container is BorderLayout.CENTER.